# Applescript for Outlook v15 - Recipients won't populate

Tags: outlook, applescript

I have copied some scripts on the site and the result is that Outlook creates a new forwarded message but the recipient is blank.  Have tried multiple forms but always the blank recipient.  It's a script I will only run for messages I manually select, so I can't use a simple forwarding rule in the app.
Any ideas?

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"

    repeat with eachSelectedMessage in selectedMessages

        set theForwardedMessage to forward eachSelectedMessage with opening window
        make new recipient at theForwardedMessage with properties {email address:{address:"recipient@somewhere.com", name:"Lumpkin Skinbark"}}
        send theForwardedMessage

    end repeat

end tell
```

Comment: 2017-04-26  7:32 PM CT -- I'm having the same issue.  I need to forward a message, but set the recipients and subject BEFORE I send it.  Changes to the Subject are shown in the Forward window, but I can't find a way to show the new recipients.

Answer (score 0):

New information:  It turns out the *recipient* is being populated correctly and put in my Outbox, but not being sent.  In addition, a new window pops up with the same forwarded message and a blank *recipient*.  That new window was the one I saw that led me to believe the *recipient* was not populating.

My workaround for now is to periodically hit the send/receive button in Outlook to send the messages sitting in the Outbox (I don't know why they don't just get sent automatically like everything else).  Then I added:

close window 1

to close the open window -- don't know why it's created and don't want it, but might as well just close it and move on.

So I do have it working, but it's not elegant.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out how to make this work:  DON'T Open the forwarded email window until AFTER you've set the email properties, especially the Recipients.

Here's my test script:

```
set newSubjectStr to "TEST -- DON'T OPEN at first."
set recipientEmail to "somebody@InvalidDomainName.com"

tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
  set selMsg to current messages
  set oMsg to item 1 of selMsg

  set subjectStr to subject of oMsg

  set oFwdMsg to ¬
    forward oMsg without opening window ## This is KEY.  Don't Open Window

  make new recipient at oFwdMsg ¬
    with properties {email address:{address:recipientEmail}}

  set subject of oFwdMsg to newSubjectStr

  --- NOW OPEN FWD EMAIL WINDOW ---
  open oFwdMsg

end tell

--- SEND NOW IF NO MORE CHANGES ---

-- Works fine if I manually send, or use keyboard shortcut --

-- Send and Close Window ---
delay 0.2
tell application "Microsoft Outlook" to activate
tell application "System Events"
  key code 36 using {command down} -- CMD-RETURN
end tell

--- BELOW SEND BY SCRIPT LEAVES MSG IN OUTBOX ---

--send oFwdMsg
--close window 1
--sync folder "Outbox"
```

NOTE to Moderators:  Is there a way to get syntax highlight for AppleScript?

Comment: The normal syntax for that would be putting something like `<!-- language: lang-cpp -->` before your code block, the example being for C++. But I'm not sure if applescript highlighting is supported, you can try if something from [this list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109) is close enough.